# PHP/Codeigniter classes and methods definition

Tags: php, class, codeigniter, methods

i have a class like this:

```
class Asd{

function index(){
$this->doSomenthing();

}

function doSomenthing(){

}

}
```

i'm using codeigniter so doSomenthing == http://www.site.com/asd/dosomenthing;

i would like to leave that method as "private" it can be used but not accessed by http requests, it should be used only from the other methods inside the class.

Does i need to declare that method as `private function doSomenthing(){}` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can prefix the "doSomething"-method with an underscore. That way it wont be accessed via the URL request.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#private

Comment: Thats CodeIgniter implementation

Comment: Just declaring it as private is enough in codeigniter. No need for remap.

Comment: i used private function _doSomenthing() but i receive the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PRIVATE

Comment: @itachi but i receive error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PRIVATE

Comment: It is a parse error. It can be due to anything. Post the whole controller.